# Start of session fails Laravel

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5

Sometimes when I log in to Laravel using the Auth library I get this error:

```
TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68:
```

To fix it, I must put the logout in the url and login again. I still could not determine why this error arises. Anything would help me

Comment: you are missing csrf token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@csrf` must be within you [login form](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/csrf#csrf-introduction)

Comment: But in the head I use this: {!! csrf_token () !!}. For the ajax, I do not know if it has to do with something